# Is it possible to use Paypal's button feature to allow users to pay each other on my website?

Tags: html, paypal

I am creating a website where I would like the users to be able to create a profile, and choose to either sell or purchase items. My question is, like the title states, how would I allow my users to pay each other? Is it possible with paypals button feature? It is for a project so it doesn't need to be perfect, but I would like it to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest integration of PayPal Checkout is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client ; you will need a live ClientID for live payments.

Payments can be directed to a specified email address by adding a `payee` object in the `purchase_units`, [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/).